# Understanding Node.js Environment: Handling Multiple Customers in WhatsApp ChatGPT Integration

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, openai-api

I am handling an automated program integrated with chatGPT into Whatsapp.

The program is triggered whenever I missed a phone call from a customer or in another case I received an email message from a customer provided his phone number and i direct him to chatGPT assist on WhatsApp to the corresponding number. Or in a regular case whenever someone simple start the chat by sending a text to my WhatsApp.

The listener event client.on(message) (in code) is triggered for any message has been sent to my Whatsapp.
Now the issue is, I don't understand well how nodeJS environment works, I have an idea that it's 1 core but it can handle multiple I/O in asynchronous way.

In case I am having multiple customers at the same time connected to my program, will the global variables be identical on the same run-time for all customer or each connected customer his own "environment" in the program?

Do I have to use threads in this case? but still I have an idea about threads that they also share memory

this is my index.js:

```
//global variable
let protocol_number 
let source

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  // Check if the message is from the customer you want to converse with
  console.log('protcol num on message: ',protocol_number,' message from: ',message.from)
  const isCustomer = message.from === protocol_number; //check if same number whose initiated first chat  
  const customerMessage = message.body.trim().toLowerCase();
 
  if (isCustomer && source ==='GMAIL') {
   
    logger.info(`Incoming Message from Customer: ${message.from}: ${customerMessage}`);

    // Use ChatGPT to generate a response based on the customer's message
    const chatGptResponse = await AutoReplyAfterMissedCall(customerMessage);

    // Send the response back to the customer
    if (chatGptResponse) {
      message.reply(chatGptResponse.trim());
    }
  } else if(isCustomer && source ==='GMAIL') {
    logger.info(`Incoming Message from Customer: ${message.from}: ${customerMessage}`);

    // Use ChatGPT to generate a response based on the customer's message
    const chatGptResponse = await AutoReplyForGmail(customerMessage);
    // Send the response back to the customer
    if (chatGptResponse) {
      message.reply(chatGptResponse.trim());
    } else { //normal chat
      const chatGptResponse = await normalGPTchat(customerMessage);
      if (chatGptResponse) {
        message.reply(chatGptResponse.trim());
      }
    }
  }
});
```

also for who knows, using chatgpt model you have to save the history for the whole conversation so chatgpt knows whats going. I am saving the messages in array and send again to chatgpt and save his response into array including the client response.

```
// Generate answer from prompt
const AutoReplyAfterMissedCall = async (messageFromCustomer) => {
  let response

  try {
    if(!messageFromCustomer){ //conversation already started and make chatgpt reply to message
     response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model : "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      max_tokens: 300,
      messages : [
        {
          role: "system",
          content : myPrompt
        }
      ]
    }) } else{ //chatgpt start converastion after missed call
      //console.log("chatgpt will read this now:", missedCalledAndBotAlreadySentFirstMessagePrompt + "\n" +messagesHistory)

      messagesHistory.push({role : "user", content: messageFromCustomer})

       response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
        model : "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        max_tokens: 1200,
        messages : messagesHistory2

      })
    }
    console.log("responseL ", response.choices[0].message)
    messagesHistory.push(response.choices[0].message)
    return response.choices[0].message.content;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    logger.error("Error while generating Answer");
  }
}
```

My 2 solutions that came to mind:
1-  use data structure for each user and point to the generated id on run-time to the messages history array?
2- start new process from each user (memory not being shared but i think its can lead to more complexity )
Note: I am not using database and also not thinking about using database

Answer (score 0):

In a Node.js environment, each incoming message is handled by an event-driven, single-threaded model. The code you provided is an event handler for the "message" event, and it runs asynchronously for each incoming message.
Regarding your concern about global variables, in the code you provided, protocol_number and source are declared as global variables. In a Node.js environment, these variables will be shared among all clients because Node.js is single-threaded. If you have multiple customers connected simultaneously, the same variables will be accessed and modified by different events (messages) concurrently. This can lead to unexpected behavior and data corruption.
To handle multiple customers simultaneously without conflicts, you should avoid using global variables for customer-specific data. Instead, you should maintain customer-related information within the context of each event or use closures to create isolated scopes for each customer. Consider something like this,

```js
// Event handler function
const handleMessage = (message, protocol_number, source) => {
 //...enter the logic here
}

// Client event listener
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  // set protocol_number and source based on your logic
  let protocol_number = //...assign protocol number based on your logic 
  let source = //...assign source based on your logic 
  // Pass customer-specific data to the event handler
  handleMessage(message, protocol_number, source)
})
```